# Python list to txt

Tags: python, list, text, io

I need this function to output to a .txt file, with what I have below it is returning only last row of integers.

```
def random_grid(file):
    grid = []
    num_rows = raw_input("How many raws would you like in your grid? ")
    num_columns = raw_input("How many columns would you like in your grid? ")
    min_range = raw_input("What is the minimum number you would like in your grid? ")
    max_range = raw_input("what is the maximum number you would like in your grid? ")
    for row in range(int(num_rows)):
        grid.append([])
        for column in range(int(num_columns)):
            grid[row].append(random.randint((int(min_range)),(int(max_range))))         
    for row in grid:
        x = (' '.join([str(x) for x in row])) 
        print x

        with open(r"test.txt", 'w') as text_file:
            text_file.write(x)
```

If the user choose a 3 by 3 grid, a low number of 1 and high number of 9 it could print like this.

```
1 2 3    
4 5 6   
7 8 9
```

I am only getting

```
7 8 9
```

in my outputted .txt file

Comment: You're not appending to the file, you're overwriting on each iteration

Comment: Use open(r"test.txt", 'a') as explained in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Or manage the matrix through numpy wich is more efficient and write it to file through [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option of `open`, `w`, will overwrite the file's contents. Use `a` to append instead, but also put a newline character `\n` after each line.

```
def random_grid(file):
    grid = []
    num_rows = raw_input("How many raws would you like in your grid? ")
    num_columns = raw_input("How many columns would you like in your grid? ")
    min_range = raw_input("What is the minimum number you would like in your grid? ")
    max_range = raw_input("what is the maximum number you would like in your grid? ")
    for row in range(int(num_rows)):
        grid.append([])
        for column in range(int(num_columns)):
            grid[row].append(random.randint((int(min_range)),(int(max_range))))         
    for row in grid:
        x = (' '.join([str(x) for x in row])) 
        print x

        with open(r"test.txt", 'a') as text_file:
            text_file.write(x)
            text_file.write("\n")
```

The other, more efficient way to do it is to move your file-writing code outside the loop, like this:

```
def random_grid(file):
    grid = []
    num_rows = raw_input("How many raws would you like in your grid? ")
    num_columns = raw_input("How many columns would you like in your grid? ")
    min_range = raw_input("What is the minimum number you would like in your grid? ")
    max_range = raw_input("what is the maximum number you would like in your grid? ")
    for row in range(int(num_rows)):
        grid.append([])
        for column in range(int(num_columns)):
            grid[row].append(random.randint((int(min_range)),(int(max_range))))    
    x = ""
    for row in grid:
        x += (' '.join([str(x) for x in row])) + "\n" 
        print x

    with open(r"test.txt", 'w') as text_file:
        text_file.write(x)
```

Comment: This, too, will have unexpected and probably unwanted behaviour if OP executes this code more than once. Better leave it with `w` but open the file outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You need to append to the file instead of overwrite it

Change

```
with open(r"test.txt", 'w') as text_file:
```

to

```
with open(r"test.txt", 'a') as text_file:
```

for append mode

or move the `with open(r"test.txt", 'w') as text_file:` to above the `for row in grid` loop

```
import random

def random_grid(file):
    grid = []

    num_rows = int(raw_input("How many rows would you like in your grid? "))
    num_columns = int(raw_input("How many columns would you like in your grid? "))
    min_range = int(raw_input("What is the minimum number you would like in your grid? "))
    max_range = int(raw_input("What is the maximum number you would like in your grid? "))

    for _ in range(num_rows):
        grid.append([random.randint(min_range,max_range) for _ in range(num_columns)])

    grid_str = '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in grid)

    with open(r"test.txt", 'w') as text_file:
        text_file.write(grid_str)
```